# NodeRed to MongoDB operation with a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, javascript-objects, node-red

So for a part school exercise, part my own project, I'm trying to make a NodeRed server that returns weather data, saves it to MongoDB and returns it on future searches for the same location.

My NodeRed server is trying to complete a replaceOne() operation to a remote MongoDB database, using the "node-red-contrib-mongodb4" v 2.3.0 node. The aim is to check if an document with three matching values exists (city, country, openweathermap_id). If it does, replace it. If it does not, make a new document.

The issue is that the object passed to the MongoDB node prompts an "MongoInvalidArgumentError: Document must be a valid JavaScript object" error and I am not entirely sure why, although I think it is because of the operation being done, as insertOne() works.

Node homepage:https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-mongodb4

The error is not with the connection configuration, other operations to the same MongoDB database work fine.

I've tried multiple different structures and methods for the object. Here is the most recent one.

This object (msg.payload) is passed to the function node.

```
{"city":"Happy Place","country":"Over There","weather":"Clouds","tempc":14.2,"temp_maxc":15,"temp_minc":14,"humidity":84,"pressure":1023,"windspeed":2.57,"winddirection":210,"clouds":40,"description":"The weather in Happy place at coordinates: 32.2125, 75.1209 is Clouds (scattered clouds).","openweathermap_id":111,"timestamp":"2023-08-24T15:06:09.219Z"}
```

Also tried wrapping the object in an array, that method works with insertOne() operation but not with replaceOne()

Here is the code of the function node that leads to the MongoDB node:

```
msg.filter = {
    city: {$eq: msg.payload.city},
    country: {$eq: msg.payload.country},
    openweathermap_id: { $eq: msg.payload.openweathermap_id }
};
 
msg.replacement = { 
    city: msg.payload.city,
    country: msg.payload.country,
    weather: msg.payload.weather,
    tempc: msg.payload.tempc,
    temp_maxc: msg.payload.temp_maxc,
    temp_minc: msg.payload.temp_minc,
    humidity: msg.payload.humidity,
    pressure: msg.payload.pressure,
    windspeed: msg.payload.windspeed,
    winddirection: msg.payload.winddirection,
    clouds: msg.payload.clouds,
    description: msg.payload.description,
    openweathermap_id: msg.payload.openweathermap_id,
    timestamp: msg.payload.timestamp
};

msg.options = {
    upsert: true
};
return msg;
```

Here is a picture of the MongoDB node settings.

[image: MongoDB node settings]

I'm having trouble understanding why exactly this is not a valid JavaScript object.

Comment: If you have a solution please add it as an answers not an edit to the question. Questions with answers score higher in search so make it easier for others to find

Answer (score -1):

I did not realize all of the CRUD values had to be inside the `msg.payload` as a `array`. I thought only the values for the document need to be.

Here is the working code for anybody else who runs into this:

```
msg.payload = [

    {city: { $eq: msg.payload.city },
    country: { $eq: msg.payload.country },
    openweathermap_id: { $eq: msg.payload.openweathermap_id }},
    {city: msg.payload.city,
    country: msg.payload.country,
    weather: msg.payload.weather,
    tempc: msg.payload.tempc,
    temp_maxc: msg.payload.temp_maxc,
    temp_minc: msg.payload.temp_minc,
    humidity: msg.payload.humidity,
    pressure: msg.payload.pressure,
    windspeed: msg.payload.windspeed,
    winddirection: msg.payload.winddirection,
    clouds: msg.payload.clouds,
    description: msg.payload.description,
    openweathermap_id: msg.payload.openweathermap_id,
    timestamp: msg.payload.timestamp},
    {upsert: true}
    ];

return msg;
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of question asker.*</sub>